# Skip `if` in case that statement is not possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails contoller I have this code:

```
    if Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).patient_id == nil 
     .........
    else
     .........
```

So at the time I get a error when there are no `params[:photo_id]`:

```
    Couldn't find Photo without an ID
```

I know that I could fix it with: For example:

```
    if(params[:photo_id]) && (Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).patient_id == nil)
```

But now I tried to write an exception "how its called I think":

```
if Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).patient_id == nil rescue false
```

That throws a new error:

```
syntax error, unexpected modifier_rescue, expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' if
```

So what did a wrong?(I'm beginner in programming!)

Comment: anti-pattern: The `rescue false` will rescue *any* errors in the line - from RecordNotFounds, to NameErrors, or typos that subsequent edits of the source introduce... best to not do it ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need some parens.

```
if (Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).patient_id == nil rescue false)
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is wrong. Try:

```
begin
  if Photo.find(params[:photo_id]).patient_id == nil 
   .........
  else
   .........
rescue
  false
end
```

Comment: But this exception is for the whole code block right? Means that when if is wrong else also wont be triggered?

Answer (score 1):

`Photo.find_by_id(params[:photo_id]).try(:patient_id)`

Avoid using exceptions for situations that are not exceptional... and by the sounds of it, you're expecting to occasionally to have a Photo that doesn't get found.